# Button getting underline iOS 8.4 Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uibutton

I am seeing a weird thing happening after I updated to Xcode 6.4. Randomly some of my buttons are getting underlined!! I have seen this happen to some of my colleagues too. Does anyone know how to fix this? I am creating buttons in XIBs and Storyboards.

[image]

Both "Help me" and "Past Conversation" are UIButtons here.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It may be a bug. iOS has an accessibility feature that underlines buttons.

Comment: Do you know how to get that fixed?

Comment: Was this in the simulator or on a real device?

Comment: Check whether Buttons Title property to "Attribute" or "Plain" & if "Attribute" then check whether Underline is enabled .Right click on text & select Font then you can see whether underline is enabled or not.

Comment: @kdogisthebest on both!

Comment: @poojathorat Yes I have already checked that! And its plain... not attributed.